# Texture Not Appearing on the model

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, texture-coordinates

I followed the blender Guru tutorial and modeled the Anvil. I made 2 models The larger one is mine where the texture seems to work fine. But the small one in foreground was followed from tutorial and the front lower part is blank.

I know the texturing is less than ideal but this is my 1st time actually UV mapping.

[The Texture Not appearing on the lower front part of Anvil[image: ][1]]

[image]

Solutions tried
1. deleting and re-applying
2. changing normals (Shift + n and ctrl+shift+n)
3. adding unwanted seams
4. restarting blender.
5. thinking of doing it all over again!
6. clearing seam and doing a smart UV

Smart UV works without a fault, but the textures are all wrong.

The one in the background seems to be fine yet I've to tune the textures but here nothing is happening.

So what did I do wrong?

I'm on blender 2.8

Here is the file link

[image]

The geometry is less than ideal btw so I turned on the subdivision adjust edit cage in modifier panel.